# distinct roots of the equation $A\sin^3 x+B\cos^3 x+C =0$

Tags: trigonometry

> The number of distinct roots of the equation $A\sin^3 x+B\cos^3 x+C =0$
>
> no two of which differ by $2\pi$ is, Where $A,B,C\in \mathbb{R}$

$\bf{(a)}\;\;\;\;\;\; 3\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\;\;\;\;\; 4\;\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;\;\;\;\;\; 6\;\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;\;\;\;\;\; infinite$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Using $$\sin 3x =3\sin x -4\sin^3 x\Rightarrow 4\sin^3 x=3\sin x-\sin 3x$$ and
$$\cos 3x = 4\cos^3 x-3\cos x\Rightarrow 4\cos^3 x=\cos 3x+3\cos x$$

So we get $$A(4\sin^3 x) +B(4\cos^3 x)+4C=0$$

So $$A(3\sin x-\sin 3x)+B(\cos 3x+3\cos x)+4C=0$$

I did not understand How can I solve that question, Help me

Thanks

Comment: if $C$ is too large the solution is $0$

Comment: Are there more conditions on $A$, $B$, and $C$?  For example, if $A=1$, $B=1$, and $C=3$, then since $|\sin(x)|,|\cos(x)|\leq 1$, the equation would have no roots.

Comment: In the case where $A=B$, then the derivative of the expression is $3A\sin(x)\cos(x)(\sin(x)-\cos(x))$.  This only has finitely many zeros in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ (and are easy), so you can use IMT in this case.

Comment: Something to try (but it's somewhat messy).  You can replace
$
\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
$
Plug this in and clear fractions.  You'll be left with a degree $6$ polynomial, but the roots will include the roots of the desired equation.  You will, however, need to check $\sin(x)=0$ and $\cos(x)=-1$ (corresponding to $t=\infty$) separately.

Comment: Is it infinite??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, observe that if $A=0$, $B=0$, and $C=0$, then there are infinitely many solutions.  This, however is boring, so we'll exclude this case.

Using the parameterization $\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ for $\sin$ and $\cos$, (and clearing fractions) we get the equation
$$
8At^3+B(1-t^2)^3+C(1+t^2)^3=0.
$$
By expanding, this becomes
$$
(C-B)t^6+3(B+C)t^4+8At^3+3(C-B)t^2+(B+C)=0.
$$

We can use Descartes' rule of signs to bound the number of roots.  There are at most $3$ sign changes since some of the coefficients repeat.  Replacing $t$ by negative $t$, shows the same structure, so there are at most $3$ negative roots.

The one case that is missing is when $t=\infty$, in this case, $\sin(x)=0$ and $\cos(x)=-1$, which is a solution only when $B+C=0$.  In this case, the polynomial also has a root at $t=0$ and the equation above simplifies to
$$
2Ct^6+8At^3+6Ct^2=0
$$
The LHS has at most $2$ sign changes (observe that for $t>0$ or $t<0$, one case will have no sign variation).

This shows that when $A$, $B$, and $C$ are not all zero, there are at most $6$ solutions (and also shows the dependence on the values of $A$, $B$, and $C$).

Comment: (+1) Are these parameterizations well-known? Do they have some name? I have not seen them! :)

Comment: The parametrizations are used in number theory for finding Pythagorean triples and in complex analysis as a version of stereographic projection.

Answer (score 2):

See after simplifying use double angle formula so $(2\sin x+\sin x-\sin 3x)=2\sin x-2\cos 2x \sin x=2 \sin x(1-\cos 2x)$ same goes for other so it becomes $2\cos x(1+\cos 2x)$ thus simplifying further you get $a \sin x(1-\cos 2x)+b\cos x(1+\cos 2x)+2c=0$ now you just need values of $cos,sin$ where $c$ has a considerable limit according to $\sin,\cos$ . If $a$ and $b$ are big too then its simply infinite values.

Comment: $\sin (x)-\sin(3x)=\color{red}{-}2\cos(2x)\sin (x)$. Notice the minus sign! :)

Comment: @HR Thanks! ...

Comment: You are welcome! :) Why you don't put the ` \ ` for the functions sin and cos? :)

Comment: Oh we have to i thought its just like numbers from next time ill put

Comment: This time, I put them for you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here, I found a restriction for the constants $A$, $B$, $C$ that wanted to share. We know by the well-known inequalities $|\sin x| \le 1$ and $|\cos x| \le 1$ that

$$-(|A|+|B|) \le A\sin^3 x+B\cos^3 x \le (|A|+|B|)$$

So, if we wish the equation to have a root we must have

$$-(|A|+|B|) \le -C \le (|A|+|B|)$$

Or equivalently

$$|C| \le |A|+|B|$$